# Store multiple Checkbox values in Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, checkbox, google-cloud-firestore

I develop an applicaion for elderly, when they sing up, the app requires from them to select which chronic disease they have from multiple `Checkbox` that in `DropDown`.
then I want to store these multiple choices in Cloud Firestore, I need to know how to stroe it?
my code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Constants.dart';
import 'checkBox.dart';
class ChronicDiseaseDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  Color borderColor;
  Color hintColor;
  Color iconColor;
  ChronicDiseaseDropDown({
    this.borderColor = white,
    this.hintColor = white,
    this.iconColor = white,
  });
  @override

  //List<Map<String, String>> chronicDisease= [{'id':'1', 'disease':'أمراض القلب'},];

  final chronicDiseaseList = const [
    {'id': 1, 'disease': 'أمراض القلب'},
    {'id': 2, 'disease': 'أمراض السكري'},
    {'id': 3, 'disease': 'أمراض الجهاز التنفسي'},
    {'id': 4, 'disease': 'أمراض السرطان'},
    {'id': 5, 'disease': 'أمراض ارتفاع ضغط الدم'},
  ];

  bool isHeartDisease = false;
  bool isDiabetes = false;
  bool isRespiratorySystemDisease = false;
  bool isCancer = false;
  bool isHighBloodDisease = false;



  String dropdownValue = 'First';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: 350,
      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        iconSize: 50,
        iconEnabledColor: iconColor,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'الأمراض المزمنة',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: hintColor),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: borderColor,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CheckboxSelectorPage(isHeartDisease),
                Text(
                  chronicDiseaseList[0]['disease'],
                  style: textStyle1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CheckboxSelectorPage(isDiabetes),
                Text(
                  chronicDiseaseList[1]['disease'],
                  style: textStyle1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CheckboxSelectorPage(isRespiratorySystemDisease),
                Text(
                  chronicDiseaseList[2]['disease'],
                  style: textStyle1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CheckboxSelectorPage(isCancer),
                Text(
                  chronicDiseaseList[3]['disease'],
                  style: textStyle1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CheckboxSelectorPage(isHighBloodDisease),
                Text(
                  chronicDiseaseList[4]['disease'],
                  style: textStyle1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ].toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to store checkbox values in field ChronicDisease:
[image]

**Editied part:**

CheckboxSelectorPage class code

```
class CheckboxSelectorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isChecked = false;

  CheckboxSelectorPage(this.isChecked, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CheckboxSelectorPageState createState() => _CheckboxSelectorPageState();
}

class _CheckboxSelectorPageState extends State<CheckboxSelectorPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        widget.isChecked = value;
        setState(() {
          widget.isChecked = value;
        });
      },
      value: widget.isChecked,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add a screenshot of the page to understand the logic? It's hard to tell how are you trying to upload that data (e.g. all at once by a click of a button, or one by one as they check them, etc.)..

Comment: @osaxma which page do you mean?

Comment: the page where the user has to click on those checkboxes..

Comment: @osaxma I have edited my question and put 3 pictures

Comment: Do you want to upload these data at the same time with age, weight, and topic of interests after the user clicks the button of creating account? If so, where are you storing these values? In other words, are you using any state management technique? It's hard to tell because I cannot see the parent widget code nor the code for `CheckboxSelectorPage` and there are many ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: @osaxma yes I want to upload these data with age, weight and so on. I edited my question and I added CheckboxSelectorPage class code.

Comment: @osaxma we dont really need the code firebase has fine documentation on how to upload an array of booleans to firestore.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying you want an array of booleans. If so it would look something like this.

```
yourDocRef.update({
    ChronicDiseases: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(<your booleans here>)
});
```

to get the document ref you will have to make a query because you don't have a predictable doc id but the code above will add to that array once you create a reference to the specific doc. Maybe make the document id the user's id for easier look up. Not sure if you have checked this post but this is your answer here.